# jQuery: remove an element being an string at the beginning

Tags: jquery

I expect not to get "hello" after pressing the button on the code below. So.. how can I remove the `span` element from `foo` variable and append it to `body`?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var foo = '<div><span>hello</span></div>';
  $(foo).find('span').remove();
  $('body').append($(foo));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click here</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove an element from text. Convert it to a jQuery object by wrapping the string `'<div><span>hello</span></div>'` with `$()` like so:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var foo = $('<div>-<span>hello</span>-</div>');
  $(foo).find('span').remove();
  $('body').append($(foo));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click here</button>
```

I've added hyphens so that you can see that the `<span>` is being removed, but elements are still being added.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `'<div><span>hello</span>world</div>'` inside `$()` so its a jQuery object. That is all you need!

I have added string `world` in the `<div>` so you know that `<span>` was removed after clicking the button.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var foo = $('<div><span>hello</span>world</div>');
  $(foo).find('span').remove();
  $('body').append($(foo));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click here</button>
```